# Proper handling of context data in libaio callbacks?

Tags: linux, asynchronous, io, aio

I'm working with kernel-level async I/O (i.e. `libaio.h`). Prior to submitting a `struct iocb` using `io_submit` I set the callback using `io_set_callback` that sticks a function pointer in `iocb->data`. Finally, I get the completed events using `io_getevents` and run each callback.

I'd like to be able to use some context information within the callback (e.g. a submission timestamp). The only method by which I can think of doing this is to continue using `io_getevents`, but have `iocb->data` point to a struct with context and the callback.

Is there any other methods for doing something like this, and is `iocb->data` guaranteed to be untouched when using `io_getevents`? My understanding is that there is another method by which `libaio` will automatically run callbacks which would be an issue if `iocb->data` wasn't pointing to a function.

Any clarification here would be nice. The documentation on `libaio` seems to really be lacking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution, which I would imagine is typical, is to "derive" from iocb, and then cast the pointer you get back from `io_getevents()` to your struct. Something like this:

```
struct my_iocb {
    iocb cb;
    void* userdata;
    // ... anything else
};
```

When you issue your jobs, whether you do it one at a time or in a batch, you provide an array of *pointers* to `iocb` structs, which means they may point to `my_iocb` as well.

When you retrieve the notifications back from `io_getevents()`, you simply cast the `io_event::obj` pointer to your own type:

```
io_event events[512];
int num_events = io_getevents(ioctx, 1, 512, events, NULL);
for (int i = 0; i < num_events; ++i) {
   my_iocb* job = (my_iocb*)events[i].obj;
   // .. do stuff with job
}
```

If you don't want to block in `io_getevents`, but instead be notified via a file descriptor (so that you can block in `select()` or `epoll()`, which might be more convenient), I would recommend using the (undocumented) `eventfd` integration.

You can tie an `aiocb` to an eventfd file descriptor with `io_set_eventfd(iocb* cb, int fd)`. Whenever the job completes, it increments the eventfd by one.

Note, if you use this mechanism, it is very important to never read more jobs from the io context (with `io_getevents()`) than what the eventfd counter said there were, otherwise you introduce a race condition from when you read the eventfd counter and reap the jobs.

Comment: Yup! Hobbled together something like this last night. Your answer definitely fills in some gaps that are lacking from the man pages!